# I want an array of enemies stored - array, vector or something else

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

*I am creating a game using C++ Direct3D for Windows Phone 8.*

What's the typical approach to storing arrays with objects (enemies in this case) which have properties like matrices, positioning, speeds etc... I will most likely need to

- sort this array
- delete specific items from it
- count it
- need to maintain it easily

A: what is usual protocol?
B: any reasoning?

---

So for example, I want to make an array of 10 enemies, each will hold their position in my 3d world and each will reference a model matrix (of random choice).

Comment: Start with a vector (it meets all the posted requirements). Encapsulate the access. Come back later if it's a problem.

Comment: a `std::vector<shared_ptr<Enemy>>` could be a good starting point. Storing concrete instances could be inviting but usually you need inheritance so it could be a bad choice.

Comment: cheers guys, will do!

Comment: in terms of performance, I will most likely need to remove elements from the array in the middle (on dynamic offsets), I have read on cplusplus.com that this is expensive in vectors, in this case, at what point do I know I need to change from vectors to lists? ... I understand this is a loose question that is difficult to answer. but thanks for any help you can come up with!